# Python define funct() "not defined"

Tags: python

our class recently got into defining functions but I'm having trouble with a specific block of code. Upon running, my code yields a 'opChoose' is not defined. The traceback faults this line of code:

```
calc(opChoose,num1, num2)
```

The code below is the entirety of my code, only a few lines of code.

```
def greeting():
    print("Welcome to the calculator app!")

def menu():
    opChoose=int(input("1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, 4 for Division"))                
    return opChoose

def numbers():   
    num1=float(input("Enter your first value"))
    num2=float(input("Enter your second value"))
    return num1, num2

def calc(opChoose,num1, num2):
    if opChoose == "1":
        ans = num1 + num2

    elif opChoose == "2":
        ans2 = num1 - num2

    elif opChoose == "3":
        ans3 = num1 * num2

    elif opChoose == "4":
        ans4 = num1 / num2

    return ans, ans2, ans3, ans4, 

def display(ans, ans2, ans3, ans4):
    if opChoose == "1":
        print(ans)

    elif opChoose == "2":
        print(ans2)

    elif opChoose == "3":
        print(ans3)

    elif opChoose == "4":
        print(ans4)


greeting()

menu()

numbers()

calc(opChoose,num1, num2)

display(ans,ans2,ans3,ans4)
```

I would try to simplify this code into a smaller block for you guys to troubleshoot but I simply don't know if the other bits of code is incorrect too, any help you guys could give me would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can not acess local scope Varaible outside the Function

Comment: You return `opChoose` but forget to receive at the caller.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code, it also helps you understand what's going on. Also, please quote the error you receive verbatim and with the full backtrace. Your question title refers to a "funct()" which is nowhere in your code, just adding to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the right thing in returning the value from the function `menu()` but you need to then assign that returned value to a variable to be able to pass it to the `calc()` function. Alternatively you can pass the function call directly to the `calc()` function itself.

Either this:

```
opChoose = menu()
calc(opChoose ,num1, num2)
```

or this:

```
calc(menu(),num1, num2)
```

Know that it is going to throw errors for the same reason on `num1` and `num2` but I think from the above you can solve that issue. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactoring of your code.

```
def greeting():
    print("Welcome to the calculator app!")

def menu():
    opChoose=int(input("1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, 4 for Division"))                
    return opChoose

def numbers():   
    num1=float(input("Enter your first value"))
    num2=float(input("Enter your second value"))
    return num1, num2

def calc(opChoose,num1, num2):
    ans=0
    ans2=0
    ans3=0
    ans4=0
    if opChoose == 1:
        ans = num1 + num2
    elif opChoose == 2:
        ans2 = num1 - num2
    elif opChoose ==3 :
        ans3 = num1 * num2
    elif opChoose == 4:
        ans4 = num1 / num2
    return ans, ans2, ans3, ans4 

def display(opChoose,ans, ans2, ans3, ans4):
    if opChoose == 1:
        print(ans)

    elif opChoose == 2:
        print(ans2)

    elif opChoose ==3:
        print(ans3)

    elif opChoose == 4:
        print(ans4)


greeting()
opChoose=menu()
num1, num2=numbers()
ans,ans2,ans3,ans4=calc(opChoose,num1, num2)
display(opChoose,ans,ans2,ans3,ans4)
```

1. In your code you call `menu()` and other functions but you don't save the data they return. You need to assign to a variable for further processing or otherwise save the value.
2. You created `opChoose` as `int` but you are comparing it with a string (`"1"`) variable -- `int` 1 and `"1"` can never be the same.

   ```
   a=1
   if(a=="1"):
             print("this will never be printed")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Having the calculation return a lot of `None` variables for paths not taken seems like an ... odd design.  Perhaps look at this instead.

```
def greeting():
    print("Welcome to the calculator app!")

def menu():
    opChoose=int(input("1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, 4 for Division"))                
    return opChoose

def numbers():   
    num1=float(input("Enter your first value"))
    num2=float(input("Enter your second value"))
    return num1, num2

def calc(opChoose, num1, num2):
    # opChoose is an int; don't compare it to a string
    if opChoose == 1:
        ans = num1 + num2
    elif opChoose == 2:
        # The answer goes to the same variable in each case
        ans = num1 - num2
    elif opChoose == 3:
        ans = num1 * num2
    elif opChoose == 4:
        ans = num1 / num2

    return ans

# Very tempted to comment out this gratuitous verbosity
greeting()
# Capture the value from the function call
op = menu()
# Capture the values from the function call
n1, n2 = numbers()
# Capture the value from the function call
value = calc(op, n1, n2)
# No need for a separate function for this really
print(value)
```

I used different variable names in the main flow to emphasize that the variables inside the function calls are entirely different, and you cannot access variables inside a function from outside, or vice versa, without making additional explicit arrangements.

Making functions which do only one thing is a good idea in general, but perhaps this is still taking it a bit too far.  Functions which don't do anything useful in isolation are just obscuring the flow of the code.